# In wso2 api cloud is it possible to add custom sequence for manipulating request and response to/from back end service

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-cloud

From my understanding of the regular WSO2 API Manager product I could create multiple synapse-configurations and register them as (global or api specific) sequences by placing them in the proper directory.

I would then utilize the Sequence configuration capabilites on the "Manage screen" to apply different sequences to the request and response payloads of the backend.

I read the documentation at https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/Key+Concepts#KeyConcepts-Sequences as it is not possible to add more but I wanted to ask specifically.

Is it at all possible to do this type of manipulation in the current version of public API cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have talked with the relevant teams and this is how you can add a sequence in the API Cloud. Although I mentioned about adding a sequence via the Gateway's carbon console (and said it was broken), WSO2 API Manager product is not a position to make it working (this is a known limitation). If I explain the reason in simple terms, to support it they will need to ship a lot of mediator UIs which will make the product similar to the WSO2 ESB. Following is what you can do.

1. Use WSO2 Developer Studio to create the sequence you want.https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS371/Creating+ESB+Artifacts#CreatingESBArtifacts-Workingwithsequences
2. Go to API Gateway at https://gateway.api.cloud.wso2.com/carbon
   You need to login to the gateway. Username is email@tenantDomain. If your email abc@gmail.com and tenant domain (or the organisation key is xyz) you need to give **abc.gmail.com@xyz** as the username (note the @ in the email being replaced with a DOT). Go to "Manage" in the top level menu of API Cloud and you will be able to figure out your organisation key.
3. Go to Resources -> Browse menu and navigate to  /_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences/ registry path. Upload your sequence to in, out or fault folders based on your requirement. This will be then available when you create APIs via the API Publisher.

Comment: Thank you. Able to add and use the sequence now

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You have to follow the below steps.

1. Go to API Gateway at https://gateway.api.cloud.wso2.com/carbon
2. You need to login to the gateway. Username is email@tenantDomain. If your email abc@gmail.com and tenant domain (or the organisation key is xyz) you need to give abc.gmail.com@xyz as the username (note the @ in the email being replaced with a DOT). Go to "Manage" in the top level menu of API Cloud and you will be able to figure out your organisation key.
3. After login, you can go to sequence menu and add a sequence. I tried these steps just now and realised there is a broken page at add sequence. We are in the process of fixing it. Will keep you updated.

Difference of API Cloud and API Manager standalone version is, you have to store the sequence in the registry for it to be available at the API Publishing time.

We'll be adding a doc on this at the following location soon.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/About+WSO2+API+Cloud#AboutWSO2APICloud-CommonAPICloudusecases

Comment: If adding custom sequence does not work yet, you can edit one of the existing sequence to do what you need - e.g. /_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences/in/log_in_message.xml can be turned into any inbound request, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I have created a sequence. I'll try it as soon as it is possible. Adding or editing sequences doesn't seemt to work at the moment when accessing https://gateway.api.cloud.wso2.com/carbon

Comment: Please see my second answer. There won't be UI support from APIM product to add or edit a sequence. You will have to create it separately and add it to the registry.